# Add partials from the actual post content

Tags: hugo

I have this as my template:

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}
<div style="padding-top:50px"></div>


<div class="grid">
    <div style="background-color: #fce473; padding: 10px" class="{{ .Params.left_col_size }}">

        <h1>left</h1>

        <div class="grid">

            <div id="content2"></div>

            {{ partial "ui-components/barchart_content2.html" }}

        </div>

    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #7bbf51; padding: 10px" class="{{ .Params.right_col_size }}">
    right
    </div>
</div>


{{ .Content }}

{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

which successfully loads the partial "ui-components/barchart_content2.html".

However, what I really want to is something like this:

```
....
<div id="content2"></div>
  {{ partial "ui-components/{{ Params.ui-component }}" }}

....
```

and then in the content do this:

```
+++
  ....
  ui-component = "barchart_content2.html"

+++
```

so that the content editors can choose which partial is rendered without having to touch the html template.

Is something like this possible in Hugo? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [printf](https://gohugo.io/functions/printf/) function to do this. Try this:

```
{{ partial (printf "ui_components/%s" .Params.ui_component) . }}
```

And the corresponding front matter:

```
+++
  ui_component = "barchart_content2.html"
+++
```

Note that I have changed your variable of `ui-component` to `ui_component`, as hyphens are not allowed in Hugo variable names.